# How make LINQ query with GroupBy and LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-4.0

I'm using EF4 and i need to make this query with LINQ but i don't know how.

If i have 3 tables:

- ProductType
- Product
- Season

ProductType **-> one-to-many ->** Product **-> many-to-one ->** Season

i would like to have a list of all the ProductType with their Products for one Season. Please note that i need to list **ALL the ProductType** even if there's no Product inside for that Season.

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you do want a left join, as per your question, do:

```
var query = from pt in model.ProductTypes
            select new
            {
                ProductType = pt,
                Products = from p in pt.Products
                           where p.SeasonId == seasonId
                           select p
            };
```

Comment: its more readable that way. But i don't understand why Jon's version worked too even if it was an inner join. Thank you very much!

Comment: Inner join works fine as long as the data happens to be on both sides.

Comment: the weird thing is that i had a few ProductTypes without any Products and everything was fine. Anyway, everything works great with your solution :)

Comment: No, mine was *not* an inner join. If you look at the compiled code, it would use `Queryable.GroupJoin`, which is the closest LINQ has to a true left join. (It's often combined with `DefaultIfEmpty` to end up with a null value in the right side, but there's no need for it in this case.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var query = from pt in model.ProductTypes
            join p in model.Product.Where(p => p.SeasonId == seasonId)
               on pt.Id equals p.ProductTypeId into g
            select new { ProductType = pt, Products = g };
```

I have to admit I'm always somewhat rusty on `join ... into` but I *think* this will do what you're after.

Comment: It works! thank you! But do you know if its something that i should put im my repository or if its something that should be in the controller? If its in the repository, i will have to make a new object to be return. Im not sure that its a good way of doing this!

Comment: @Alexandre: I really don't know, to be honest.

Comment: i have decided to put it in the Controller since that its specific for the View. And its must easier!

Comment: This is an inner join, not a left join.

Comment: @Craig: Using "join into" rather than just "join" performs a group join, which includes empty right sequences when the left element doesn't match anything.